# Android - Password transformation (convert the * to a text )

Tags: java, android

This is an android class to transform the password from dot to * or star but I want to show user some pre defined text instead of star ,for that i replaced the star with a character from char array yay .But when I run the application with one tap to button .P is printed infinite times in the logger .Can any body explain ?

```
class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
static  int a=0;
char[] yay= {'P','l','e','a','s','e','w','r','i','t','e'};
@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
    return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
}
private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private CharSequence mSource;

    public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
        mSource = source; // Store char sequence
    }
    public char charAt(int index) {
        Log.v("what is the char",""+yay[a]);
        char x= yay[a]; // This is the important part
        return x;
    }
    public int length() {
        return mSource.length(); // Return default
    }

    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you want:

```
Log.v("what is the char",""+yay[index]);
char x= yay[index];
```

It prints out only "p", because `a` is always 0, therefore `yay[a]` is always "p".

---

But why do you want to do this at all? Just set the Input type of your field to `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` and android does that for you.

Comment: I have made that intentionally to check the problem ,on press of a single char  p is printed infinite times in the logger.What I dnt understand  is when i have pressed one character, p should be printed only once but that is not the case

Comment: I have a need in my app to hide the * to a pre defined string .

Comment: Obviously the android system calls your charAt method infinitley. Inspect the stacktrace to find out why.

Comment: When one char is pressed on phone,Why would the android system call charAt method infinitely? This is the main problem which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: What happens if you use my code above - does it still only print p?